# open nav when i click on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, nav

i want to open nav (active) when i click on link like i this website https://www.logura.com/ , in footer when i click on logo design or branding it directs me to another page and open particular nav. please guide me, i have tried differenlty but its not working

```
$(document).on('click', '.footer-top-2 ul.portfolio-footerList li a', function(e) {
                    
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                var activeTab = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);
                
                var hasSlash = activeTab.includes("/");
                
                if (hasSlash == true) {
                    activeTab = activeTab.split("/")[0];
                }
                
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".portfolio-2-tabs .nav-tabs li a").removeClass("active");
                $("#" + activeTab + "-link").addClass("active");
                $(".portfolio-2-tabs .tab-pane").removeClass("active");
                $("#" + activeTab).addClass("active");
                /*$('a[href="#'+ activeTab +'"]').tab('show');*/
                
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#portfolio-sec-2').offset().top - 50
                }, 'slow');
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with path hashes. For example, If I have an html file where I defined a link tag with the id of 'abc' then go to the URL https://example.com/path#abc it will scroll to the link tag. If you wanted to redirect to a URL with a path hash you can just include it in the link:

```html
<a href="https://example.com/path#extra-info">Go to Extra Info</a>
```

More information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/url/hash

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: it just take me to perticular section or div where this ID is assigned,  what i want is if i click on link on another page it takes me to that page and opens that nav like its working in this website in footer when we click on : All in one OR Logo OR branding link it takes us to that page and opens (active) that nav https://www.logura.com/

Comment: What link are you using? https://example.com/#hash or #hash? The second option will link on the current page, the first will travel to the other page and go to the hash. If you are using some kind of client-side rendering this will not work.

Comment: brother i have done it for perticular section on particular page, but i want is that if i click on link it takes me to perticular page of particular tab/nav ,